# redirect base url to custom url magento

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

```
I want to redirect my baseurl to a custom url(i.e a CMS page basically)
 base url : index.php
 custom url: home

I followed following steps:

    1. Navigate to Catalog > Url Rewrite Management
    2. Click the “Add Urlrewrite” button
    3. Select “Custom” from the “Create Urlrewrite” drop-down menu
    4. The “Urlrewrite Information” form would be completed thusly:



  ID Path: index.php
    Request Path:index.php
    Target Path: home
    Redirect: Permanent(301)
```

Then refreshed cashe. But redirection is not working. "index.php" is still showing same page
    Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To create a rewrite for the base url you have to use / instead of index.php

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

Create URL Redirect in admin panel :Marketting->URL Rewrites

Request Path: index.php 
target path: ../

it will redirect strong text to the homepage.